# str.replace : why some get replaced, some don't? Any idea?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Column name = "Insurance Type"

3 types of names in the columns "wa, wa_bep_ca" and "wa_ca".

Trying to replace these names with proper names.
Any idea on why they don't get all replaced in the column?? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Since your are applying these methods on a Series, use the Series method: `str.replace` instead of `replace`, not 100% sure, but that should also solve the problem.

Comment: Are there leading/trailing whitespace characters? Have you tried `.str.strip()` before the replacement?

Comment: If you posted the code and data as text, people could run your example code for themselves and would probably be able to post a solution very quickly. By posting code and data as a picture, that makes things more difficult for everyone. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use *replace* on the column of interest, with a dictionary specifying:

- the string to find as keys,
- the string to replace as values.

The code to do it is:

```
df['Insurance type'].replace({
    'wa_bep_ca': 'Liability + lim casco',
    'wa_ca': 'Liability + full casco',
    'wa': 'Liability only' }, inplace=True)
```

For the test I used the following DataFrame:

```
   offer_number Insurance type
0          1001             wa
1          1002      wa_bep_ca
2          1003          wa_ca
3          1004          wa_xx
```

The result is:

```
   offer_number          Insurance type
0          1001          Liability only
1          1002   Liability + lim casco
2          1003  Liability + full casco
3          1004                   wa_xx
```

(the last row does not match any of keys used, so it has not been replaced).